# Selenium WebDriver: Is there a way to count items in a dynamic list where items have hyperlinks?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a dynamic list of places displayed when a state is selected (from a drop down box). Each item in the list is a hyperlink that opens another page containing other details.
As you can see the html code below, the list is not tagged using Select or Table.
In this scenario, in Selenium, my understanding is that I will not be able to know the count of no. of places that get displayed on selecting a state since this is actually not a list.
Is my understanding correct?

(I am able to use linkText().click() on the items and it is working.)

```
<div class="blk">
    <div class="smlhead">
          Places
    </div>
    <div id="divPlacesCont" class="sbarPrnt" style="height: 179.219px;">
    <div id="divPlaces" class="tilewrap sbarcont" style="height: 179px;">
        <div class="blksmlr smlhead sngline">
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:mcSearch.placeSelected(this, '12');">hyd</a>
        </div>
        <div class="blksmlr smlhead sngline">
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:mcSearch.placeSelected(this, '7');">Hyderabad</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sbar" style="display: none;">
        <div class="sbarpos" style="height: 152.576px; top: 0px;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get reference to the WebElement by ID: divPlaces

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("divPlaces"));

// find all links inside 
List<WebElements> list = element.findElements(By.xpath(".//a"));
```

Now obviously you can check size of the list to see how many links there are.

```
list.size();
```

And do what ever you like with elements from the list.

Comment: Thank you and it worked! I had tried earlier using List<WE> but had not got the xpath correctly which would return the WE and the count. That led me to think this cannot be done using a List.